# Accessing values from a Unicode dictionary in Python

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, dictionary

I have Unicode values similar to this in a dictionary:

```
{u'id': u'100000000265946', u'name': u'Sophia N Art Fuentes'}
{u'id': u'100000538132142', u'name': u'Tatiana Vargas'}
{u'id': u'1669912701', u'name': u'Milvia Albanez'}
```

I need to access keys and values but I'm getting this error

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'

I am using Python 2.7. Is there any method to convert Unicode to ASCII? Or how do I access the values as Unicode itself?

Comment: Please show the code you use to access the data

Comment: i could not post the entire code.. for index1,val in enumerate(item):
       print val.keys() where item is  list of dictionaries and val is a dictionary which contains the above data

Comment: Are you sure its a list of dictionaries and not a list of strings that look like dictionaries? `[u"{'id': u'100000000265946', u'name': u'Sophia N Art Fuentes'}"]` vs. `[{'id': u'100000000265946', u'name': u'Sophia N Art Fuentes'}]`?

Comment: @user2401464 you can post the code to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = u"{u'id': u'100000000265946', u'name': u'Sophia N Art Fuentes'}"
>>> s.keys()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    s.keys()
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'
>>> import ast
>>> d = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> d.keys()
[u'id', u'name']
```

Comment: for index1,val in enumerate(item):
    d = ast.literal_eval(val)
    print d.keys()                                                 I tried it inside python script its showing                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\jsontocsv\jsontocsvtry.py", line 26, in <module>
    d = ast.literal_eval(val)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
    ValueError: malformed string

Comment: @user2401464 You should check what the output is for `print item[0]`

Comment: @user2401464 no it isn't , `item` is a dictionary

Comment: i just checked the type there are 2 data types in item, a dictionary with one key and value and list of dictionaries.. so when i say enumerate(item) , it accesses the list of dictionaries in item